# Simple command line chat with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, console, chat

I want to implement a simple console chat in python. 
I've already write two scripts, one server, one client and I am possible to write messages from the client to the server script over a udp socket. It's possible to open a server and a client console, so that you can read in the first and write in the second console. The next step is to write a chat, that every user can start and then you can read and write in the same console.

In the following there is my try with the help of threads. But it didn't work and I need a little bit help with the implementation. I would be very thanksful for a few tipps for a python beginner.

Thanks in advance!

```
import socket, time, datetime, threading

target_ip = raw_input("Empf-IP: ")
port = 48899

udp_socket = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET,  socket.SOCK_DGRAM )

def SendThread(threading):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = raw_input("> ")
            udp_socket.sendto(message, (target_ip,port))

def ReceiveThread(threading):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            print data
my_threads = []

send_thread = SendThread()
recv_thread = ReceiveThread()

my_threads.append(send_thread)
my_threads.append(recv_thread)  

for thread in my_threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in my_threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: "it didn't work" - please be more specific. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected behaviour (describe expected and actual behaviour)?

Comment: `threading` is a module. Use `threading.Thread` as a base class. Or better, for your simple case, just use functions e.g., `threads = [Thread(target=f) for f in [sender, receiver]]`

Comment: Sorry for my bad post. The script starts and at the moment, where I enter my first input the console just close.
threading.Thread was my first choice, but I compiled it and it gives me a syntax error on that expression.. so I've changed to threading

Comment: @Sebastian: Can you explain me that line "threads = [Thread(target=f) for f in [sender, receiver]]"? I,m not sure what should happen here..